# how to remove clusterMark on my marker on Google map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I do not like to cluster mark on my Google map I wont to display all mark point on map not group marker. my app in rails and I am using gmaps4rails gem so how can we do that?

I try with

```
 var mcOptions = {gridSize: 500, maxZoom: 10};
 markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map ,markers,mcOptions);
 but not working please give some suggestion to make it work
```

[image]

[image]

how can do in rails with gmaps4rails gem please share your idea to archive this.

Comment: please read the gem's documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this option you can remove clusterMark from your map

```
gmaps("markers" => {"data" => @results.to_gmaps4rails , "options" => {:auto_adjust => false,:do_clustering => false} })
```